Interpretation of parameter estimates from a beta regression model
I am using a beta regression model in R. I will illustrate with a simulated data to understand the interpretation. Suppose, the outcome variable is called outcome which is bounded between 0 and 1. I also have two covariates; treatment which has 3 categories (A, B and C) and iq simulated using standard normal distribution. My goal is to investigate if there is an association between the outcome and covariates.
R code to simulate data:
set.seed(1)
mydata = data.frame(outcome=runif(100),treatment = factor(sample(c("A","B","C"),100,replace=TRUE)),iq=rnorm(100))

Then we can fit a beta regression model using the betareg function.
library(betareg)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(marginaleffects)
library(ggeffects)
library(ordbetareg)
library(knitr)
library(parameters)

model_beta = betareg(outcome~factor(treatment)+iq | factor(treatment)+iq,
                     data=mydata,link="logit")
summary(model_beta)

The summary of the model is as follows. I understand there are two different parts: one for the mean model and another for the precision model. The estimates are the log odds estimate since we used the logit link.
First question: Can I make inference from the following output? Can I interpret as "If iq is increased by 1 unit then .......
Call:
betareg(formula = outcome ~ factor(treatment) + iq | factor(treatment) + iq, data = mydata, link = "logit")

Standardized weighted residuals 2:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.5729 -0.5849  0.0389  0.6002  2.0709 

Coefficients (mean model with logit link):
                   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)        -0.02176    0.17159  -0.127    0.899  
factor(treatment)B -0.13444    0.26595  -0.506    0.613  
factor(treatment)C  0.24357    0.26630   0.915    0.360  
iq                 -0.19714    0.11071  -1.781    0.075 .

Phi coefficients (precision model with log link):
                   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)         0.99059    0.20671   4.792 1.65e-06 ***
factor(treatment)B -0.68443    0.28269  -2.421   0.0155 *  
factor(treatment)C -0.12546    0.31100  -0.403   0.6867    
iq                  0.07665    0.11955   0.641   0.5214    
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 

Type of estimator: ML (maximum likelihood)
Log-likelihood: 6.014 on 8 Df
Pseudo R-squared: 0.04711
Number of iterations: 30 (BFGS) + 1 (Fisher scoring)

However, I also came across outputting something like the following (difference in probability).
  #get difference
  avg_comparisons(model_beta)%>%
  kable()

With the following output.
|term      |contrast          |   estimate| std.error|  statistic|   p.value|   s.value|   conf.low| conf.high| predicted_lo| predicted_hi| predicted|
|:---------|:-----------------|----------:|---------:|----------:|---------:|---------:|----------:|---------:|------------:|------------:|---------:|
|iq        |mean(+1)          | -0.0483355| 0.0264920| -1.8245311| 0.0680718| 3.8767987| -0.1002589| 0.0035879|    0.4774381|    0.4286290| 0.4774381|
|treatment |mean(B) - mean(A) | -0.0332144| 0.0656963| -0.5055740| 0.6131557| 0.7056745| -0.1619768| 0.0955481|    0.5110320|    0.4774381| 0.4774381|
|treatment |mean(C) - mean(A) |  0.0600606| 0.0653734|  0.9187318| 0.3582359| 1.4810184| -0.0680689| 0.1881902|    0.5110320|    0.5714338| 0.4774381|

Second question: Can I make inference using the above output? I understand the estimates in the above table is the difference in probability. Can I say the following?

If iq is increased by 1 unit then the probability of outcome decreases by 4.83% while keeping other variables fixed.
The probability of outcome increases by 6% for treatment=C vs treatment=A while keeping other variables fixed.

Third question: Is there any other simple interpretation?
Fourth question: What if I have 0's and 1's in my data for the outcome variable? I see that we can use zero-one inflated beta regression model? Any help in R would be appreciated.

Please create one post per question. I will focus on question 4 but generally encourage you to plot the data and the model predictions, which should help with your other questions. You also might find guides like this useful: https://www.andrewheiss.com/blog/2021/11/08/beta-regression-guide/. It briefly addresses intepretation of coefficients.
Anyway, if you have exact 0s and/or 1s, you need to consider why you have those. If those are "real" values, you probably shouldn't use beta-regression. However, often they result from censoring. You can easily model censored data using the brms package, which however does Bayesian modelling.
Here is an example how to do that:
set.seed(1)
mydata = data.frame(outcome = runif(100), treatment = factor(sample(c("A","B","C"),100,replace=TRUE)),iq=rnorm(100))
mydata$treatment <- factor(mydata$treatment)

#create some 0 and 1 values
mydata[sample(100, 5), "outcome"] <- 0
mydata[sample(100, 5), "outcome"] <- 1

mydata[, "censored"] <- 0

#left-censored outcome
mydata[mydata$outcome == 0, "censored"] <- -1 
mydata[mydata$outcome == 0, "outcome"] <- 1e-3 #detection limit

#right-censored outcome
mydata[mydata$outcome == 1, "censored"] <- 1 
mydata[mydata$outcome == 1, "outcome"] <- 1 - 1e-3 #detection limit

#install backend:
#install.packages("cmdstanr", repos = c('https://stan-dev.r-universe.dev', getOption("repos")))
#cmdstanr::check_cmdstan_toolchain(fix = TRUE)
#cmdstanr::install_cmdstan() 

library(brms)

model_beta_bayes <- brm(
  bf(outcome | cens(censored) ~ treatment + iq,
     phi ~ treatment + iq),
  data = mydata,
  family = Beta(link = "logit", link_phi = "log"),
  init = 0,
  chains = 4, iter = 2000, warmup = 1000,
  cores = 4, seed = 42, 
  backend = "cmdstanr"
)
summary(model_beta_bayes) 

Of course, with real data you should do model diagnostics and consider using your own priors instead of the default ones.

Thank you. Do you have any thoughts on Question 1 and 2?

Again: Plot the predictions. You will see that the logit link means that you can’t say “A unit increase of iq causes …” (beyond “an increase” or “a decrease” of outcome) because it matters from which value it increases.

I tried running the code provided above, However, I get a long error message. I paste few lines of error message as `cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-ignored-attributes" [enabled by default]
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-ignored-attributes" [enabled by default]
make: *** [/tmp/Rtmp5T358T/model-6a5a1d32d341] Error 1
Error: An error occured during compilation! See the message above for more information.`

There seems to be an issue with your setup. As a first step, ensure that all versions are updated.

Got it. Could you please provide the version you are using?

The most recent R-release, the corresponding Rtools and the most recent brms. cmdstanr was freshly installed. You could also try with the default Stan backend instead.

If your exact 0 and 1 results are not censored points, then you can try using ordered beta regression (https://www.robertkubinec.com/post/limited_dvs/). R has two implementations. the ordbetareg package uses Bayesian methods with stan. The glmmTMB package has an ordbeta family.
